# Unable to SSH into an Ubuntu server from a windows machine

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh

I'm trying to `ssh` into an Ubunto 20 server from a windows machine, but I'm still getting a password prompt.

I have added the `pvt_key_rsa` to the `.ssh/` folder in the server.

I have given  the right permissions to the `.ssh/` folder and the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

I can connect via `ssh` via a unix (Mac OSX) with no problem to the server, but when I try with Windows I get a password prompt.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe I'm missing something ? If someone could help. This is the log when I try to `ssh company@ip_address`

```bsh
    C:\Users\Smiling>ssh smiling@109.68.167.243 -v
    OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
    debug1: Connecting to 109.68.167.243 [109.68.167.243] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug1: Authenticating to 109.68.167.243:22 as 'smiling'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ohy6zRlWSJ0+pDaVfVv0zUwgHddV7fABJZpnMUv4mno
    debug1: Host '109.68.167.243' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:DVUoQXrXSRAb06VkBRXqGRU77XfemcWLwRqds7YB7zs
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:DVUoQXrXSRAb06VkBRXqGRU77XfemcWLwRqds7YB7zs
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Smiling/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
    smiling@109.68.167.243's password:
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    Permission denied, please try again.
    debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
    smiling@109.68.167.243's password:
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    Permission denied, please try again.
    debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
    smiling@109.68.167.243's password:
```

**On My local machine I have the following**

[image]

Comment: *"I have added the pvt_key_rsa to the .ssh/ folder in the server."* you should have appended the **public** key (id_rsa.pub) to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server. The private key stays on your local computer.

Comment: In the question you mention Ubuntu 20 (do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?) which is a different server system to Ubuntu 20.04 you've tagged.  Products that use the *year* format are different to the more popular *year.month* products.

Comment: @steeldriver please  add this as as an anwser and I will mark it as correct. That was actually the problem